# AzureDevOps API CodeSearch is returning old file (that has been renamed)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a service that request all our repositories then for each repository, i'm getting all the csproj and vbproj in the repository.

My problem is that it return 2 versions of the same file!

Ex:
A project has been created that way => MYPROJECT.csproj and commited,
then renamed to MyProject.csproj and commited.

But the CodeSearch Api is returning both file!
How can i know which one is the right one ?

Documentation doesn't seems to mention it or I'm not understanding which properties I need to send or which properties is telling me that it's an old file.

Documentation

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/search/code%20search%20results/fetch%20code%20search%20results?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1
```

URL

```
https://almsearch.dev.azure.com/MyOrganisation/MyProject/_apis/search/codesearchresults?api-version=5.1-preview.1
```

BODY

```
{
    'searchText': 'ext:csproj',
    'includeFacets': false,
    '$skip': 0,
    '$top': 1000,
    'filters': {
        'Project': ['MyProject']
    },
    '$orderBy': [{
        'field': 'filename',
        'sortOrder': 'ASC'
    }]
}
```

When I do the same research directly on DevOps, I see this flag over the old file

[image]

So there must be a way to tell if it's an old file!

How can I get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could reproduce this issue on my side. In Tfvc Repo, the code search result will return all versions of the file.

[image]

Based on my test, the difference between them is `versions -> changeid`.

Generally `changeid` is incremental, so you could judge the old and new versions according to the value of changeid. This is a workaround.

On the other hand,  I will help you to report this issue on our [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1174274/code-search-return-old-file-version-that-has-been.html) forum, and after confirmation by our engineer, this issue will be reported to the product team. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

Comment: thanks for your time and support, could it help too, to send it to our internal Microsoft contact?

Comment: changeId is a GUID, how do i know if it incremented?

Comment: Yes.  You are right.  Changeid can only be used for manual comparison, and you cannot use changeid to get only the latest file. It has great limitations. You can wait for our PG team to investigate this issue. I also hope this problem can be solved fundamentally.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same message (I renamed file using `git mv` command):

[image]

I got this message after committing renamed file and when I clicked on search button. However, when I refreshed page, warning goes away:

[image]

For me it looks like search on web based on some kind of locally cached indexes, but it is aware that some file was changed. Thus you won't be able to achieve this via REST API call.

Comment: It's a TFVC repository and refreshing is still showing the message over the file. But i just need a boolean or something that show that it's an old version if they can show the message their must be a property somewhere?